# JUNIPER Junos Pulse - how to apply policy to device

Tags: network, firewalls, configuration, end-points

We'd like to set up and use Juniper Junos Pulse on iphone and ipad for access to Corporate mail.

We have juniper SA and have prepared the policy, but how do we apply the policy to the devices?

Comment: Have you not read the vendor's manuals? I'd find it hard to believe that they would not explain that... Anyway, this is only marginally on-topic here, usually questions here would be more like "what kind of policy should be applied" or "how to allow access to mail" etc. Mayhaps you'd have better luck at serverfault.

Answer (score 1):

Not specifically on topic, but:

According to the Junos Pulse release notes: The Apple iPad Junos Pulse is not supported on the Apple iPad as of September 2010. Junos Pulse will be qualified to work on Apple iPad products when iOS 4.2 is realeased by Apple.

**Update** As of December 2015, the [Pulse Secure Desktop Client Supported Platforms Guide](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/pulsesecure/pulse-secure-desktop/ps-pulse-5.1r5-supportedplatforms.pdf) says that Max OSX 10.11, 10.10 and 10.9, 64 bit Safari 8.x and 7.x are supported.